# Remove first item of each array inside of array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following array in javascript:

```
DATA[
[ 3, "Name1" ],
[ 5, "Name2" ],
[ 10, "Name3" ],
[ 55, "Name4" ]
]
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
DATA[ "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4" ]
```

Is it possible in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple use-case for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let data = [
  [3, "Name1"],
  [5, "Name2"],
  [10, "Name3"],
  [55, "Name4"]
];

data = data.map(arr => arr[1]);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do this, but here's one:

```
for(var i=0;i<DATA.length;i++){
  DATA[i] = DATA[i][1];//only grab the 2nd item in the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and grab the second item of each child array to build the new array.

```js
const DATA = [
  [ 3, "Name1" ],
  [ 5, "Name2" ],
  [ 10, "Name3" ],
  [ 55, "Name4" ]
]

const newArr = DATA.map(i => i[1])

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
let data = [
  [3, "Name1"],
  [5, "Name2"],
  [10, "Name3"],
  [55, "Name4"]
];

const result =  data.map(([k, v])=>v);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var data =[[ 3, "Name1" ],[ 5, "Name2" ],[ 10, "Name3" ],[ 55, "Name4" ]];
var newdata=[];
data.forEach(function(element){
    if(Array.isArray(element)){
        newdata.push(element[1]);
    }
});
console.log(newdata);
```